# Why I get this error when trying to import decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators, django-2.2

I got an error when trying to import decorators. When I run python3 manage.py runserver the error is:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'allowed_users' from
> 'accounts.decorators'
> (/home/stela/Documents/ProjectsPython/crm/accounts/decorators.py)**

I'm trying to import: `from .decorators import unauthenticated_user, allowed_users, admin_only`

And when I hover on from it shows me

> No name 'unauthenticated_user' in module
> 'accounts.decorators'pylint(no-name-in-module)

as it the same for `allowed_users` and `admin_only`.

I installed decorators via `python3 install decorators`, but it keeps showing me this error. Someone with the same problem, what is the solution for this?

I have the 64 bit version of python (matches my computer), and I'm using version 3.8.2

Comment: do you mean via pip3?

Comment: I tried different ways via pip3 too, Requirement already satisfied: decorators in /home/stela/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.0.7)

Comment: did you try `from decorators ...` no period before decorators

Comment: I just tried this, same error...

Comment: what is the contents of the `decorators.py` file? Is there a `__init__.py` file in that directory? Why are you installing the `decorators` package from pypi?